# Any way to overwrite Blazor component html at runtime

Tags: blazor, rider

I am using Rider IDE and it is causing me problems with using correct file location in the script tag, i.e. I can't use paths relative to wwwroot but only relative to the blazor file where the script tag is used. What I was planning to do is write all my js code with file path that provides me type support, and at runtime replace it with correct path:

**SomeComponent.razor**

```html
<script type="module">
    // from: './index.js' // <- correct path
    import {destroyRef} from '../../wwwroot/index.js'; // <- incorrect path, but Rider provides type support
```

Any way to intercept html response on the server so I can make the necessary change?